# .htaccess $_GET return NULL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I try to access `$_GET`, request return NULL. I have a simple page that I'm using for testing. I don't know why I can't get these URL parameters?

`.htaccess` file:

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^article/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ article?title=$1&page=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

`article.php` file:

```
<?php
var_dump($_GET);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($_GET["title"]);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($_GET["page"]);
echo "<br>";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a href="article/myTitle/3/">Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Results:

```
array(0) { } 
NULL 
NULL 
Link
```

Comment: What is your request URL?

Comment: at least, swap RewriteRules. Now your url matches the first one

Comment: I am using the link to access $_GET

Comment: @splash58 I tried but doesn't effect

Comment: Why not rewrite to `article.php` directly and avoid a second internal rewrite?

Comment: @w3dk what do you mean exactly ? Sorry for my English, i couldn't understand.

Comment: w3dk means - what do you enter in the browser's address bar to get the results provided - and that's a good question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Options +MultiViews
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
> RewriteRule ^article/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ article?title=$1&page=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
> ```

There are a few problems here. You are probably getting a conflict with `MultiViews`. It is this that is loading `article.php` (without the query string arguments), not your first `RewriteRule` that appends the `.php` extension. But this directive would also be incorrect for a request like `article/myTitle/3/` - since this would result in `article/myTitle/3/.php`, which is clearly not correct.

You may have other requirements not mentioned here, but to make this specific example work you would only need something like:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^article/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ article.php?title=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Note that this rewrites to the actual target (`article.php`) not `article` (which would then need additional rewrites). Only use the `NC` flag if you specifically need it to be case-insensitive (you are already checking for `a-z` and `A-Z` in the regex).

Comment: Thank you. Also i add RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] bottom of the .htaccess file and change [QSA,L] to [QSA] so i can access pages without .php extension.